# Soupe = Boire ou manger ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, alimentation

Pour une soupe, quel est le meilleur verbe à employer ?

**Boire** une soupe ou **manger** une soupe ?
(je ne vais pas parler de soupe chinoise ou autres, non la classique soupe de tomate ou soupe de potiron... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'emploi de « boire » ou « manger » ne tient pas à la nourriture elle-même mais à la façon dont elle est consommée.

Je peux manger une soupe de tomate ou de légumes le soir chez moi dans une assiette à soupe avec une cuillère, mais le lendemain boire au bureau le reste de cette même soupe que je fais réchauffer au micro ondes dans un verre ou une grande tasse.

Comme dis @SergeBallesta en général on boit le bouillon, et le bouillon (surtout quand on est malade au lit) est servi dans un bol et bu du bol sans cuillère.

Il n'y a pas que la soupe qu'on peut boire ou manger selon le cas. Prenons l'exemple du yaourt qu'on peut manger à la cuillère à même le pot, ou qu'on peut boire, quand il est liquide et présenté dans une petite bouteille. On peut ainsi acheter ou faire soi-même des yaourts à boire, très pratique pour mettre dans le goûter des enfants à la récré.

Comment: +1, et puis avec les [Cuillère-Pailles](http://www.bebe-au-naturel.com/ecococoon-cuillere-paille-en-inox-sherbet--lot-de-4,jouet,produit,0-16511-,28.bio.html) on peut (presque) à la fois manger ET boire son milkshake, yaourt, ou meme sangria!

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas la cuillère-paille ! Aussi pratique pour  les amateurs de glaces, on commence à la cuillère et on peut finir à la paille !

Answer (score 5):

Classiquement, le terme le plus usité est *manger*. L'expression suivante est couramment employée envers les enfants:

> Mange ta soupe si tu veux grandir.

En revanche, on boit un bouillon.

> Hier j'étais malade. J'ai juste bu un bouillon de poule.

Comment: OK, merci ! C'est ce que je pensais mais, existe t-il un terme officiel à utiliser? (Du genre l'Académie française qui a officialisé le verbe manger pour soupe)

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @SergeBallesta, ça dépend de la consistance de la soupe et de son type. Si ce n'est pas un bouillon on utilise d'avantage manger que boire.

Answer (score 0):

Le mot soupe signifie le bout de pain au Moyen âge ,alors en ce temps on buvait le contenu liquide et on mangeait le pain.

Comment: Donc aujourd'hui on boit la soupe ?